# find and return an element of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been trying to figure this out on my own for the past couple of hours but I'm stuck.

I have an array that has a list of a person's name, age, height (in cm). I want to create a method where I use only the person's name as a parameter and searches for the name in the array; if there is no matching name, return null.

Looks like this:

```
data = new data[50];
data[0] = new data("Dan", 23, 179);
data[1] = new data("David", 20, 180);
data[2] = new data("Sharon", 19, 162);
data[3] = new data("Jessica", 22, 160);
data[4] = new data("Nancy", 25, 164);
...
numberData = 30; // this is the number of people that are in this array so far
```

This is what I've been trying so far..

```
public data findData(String name) {
   for (int i = 0; i < numberData; i++) {
        if (name == data[i]) {
            return data[i];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I know it isn't right, but I can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: name.equals(data[i])  - Reference to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Please show your `data` class. Also you would usually call classes with an upper-case first letter. Finally, it is pretty misleading when you have an array called `data`, along with a class called `data`.

Comment: You should use the property `length` of the arrays instead or using your `numberData` variable.

Answer (score 1):

array is referencing the `Data` class with name parameter so we should compare with name parameter not directly with reference of data and for string comparisons always go for [`equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) method.

```
public Data findData(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberData; i++) {
        if (name.equals(data[i].getName())) {
          return data[i];
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In case the loop doesn't execute at least once, you're missing **return value**.
2. `==` compares references, `equals` compares Strings.
3. Return `null` just in case, there is no such element in the array.
4. Class names should start with a capital letter. Please write `Data` instead of `data`.

Code:

```
public Data findData(String name) {
   for (Data d : data) {
        if (name.equals(d.getName())) {
            return d;
        } 
   }
   return null;
}
```

is what you're looking for. In the original code, `null` was returned if the `0`th element wasn't `name`.

OK, the above was a quick fix and now some theory:

The pseudo code for linear search in an array:

- Loop through all elements in an array. If any matches with the one you're looking for, return it.
- If nothing was returned, return the indicating value (`null` in our case).

Look, in the original code, on the 0th element, you decided whether to return that element or a `null`. Also, if the loop wasn't run at least once, there was no return statement to hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` to compare strings,
e.g.

```
if(name.equals(data[i].getName())) {
    statements...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to compare strings you must use the *equals* method.

Here's an example of how can you use java 8:

```
  public Data findData(Data[] datas, String name) {
    return Arrays.stream(datas).filter(data -> data.getName().equals(name)).findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use equals() to compare strings. equals() checks the actual contents of the string, `==` checks if the object references are equal.

And also, as mentioned above, move `return null` outside the loop;

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code. Assuming that your data class will have getName() method which returns the name value.

```
public data findData(String name) {
 for (int i = 0; i < numberData; i++) {
     if (name.equals(data[i].getName())) {
         return data[i];
     }
 }
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

move the return null statement out of the loop.
Oh! and yes, use the equals() method instead of ==